# Segmentation fault when calling assembly function from C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to link assembly functions to a C code for exercise.
Here's my assembly function, written in x86 assembly:

```
.code32

.section .text
.globl max_function
.type max_function, @function 
# i parametri saranno in ordine inverso a partire da 8(%ebp)

max_function:
    pushl %ebp              # save ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp         # new frame function
    movl $0, %edi           # first index is 0
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx      # ecx is loaded with the number of elements
    cmpl $0, %ecx            # check that the number of elements is not 0
    je end_function_err    #if it is, exit

    movl 12(%ebp),%edx      # edx is loaded with the array base
    movl (%edx), %eax       # first element of the array

    start_loop:
    incl %edi               #increment the index
    cmpl %edi,%ecx          #if it's at the end quit
    je loop_exit
    movl (%edx,%edi,4),%ebx   #pick the value
    cmpl %ebx,%eax              #compare with actual maximum value
    jle start_loop              #less equal -> repeat loop
    movl %ebx,%eax              #greater -> update value
    jmp start_loop              #repeat loop

    loop_exit:
    jmp end_function            #finish

end_function:                   #exit operations
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret

end_function_err:
    movl $0xffffffff, %eax            #return -1 and quit
    jmp end_function
```

It basically defines a function that finds the maximum number of an array (or it should be)

And my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int max_function(int size, int* values);

int main(){
    int values[] = { 4 , 5 , 7 , 3 , 2 , 8 , 5 , 6 } ;
    printf("\nMax value is: %d\n",max_function(8,values));
}
```

I compile them with `gcc -o max max.s max.c`.
I get a `SegmentationFault` when executing the code.

My suspect is that I don't access the value in a right manner, but I can't see why, even because I based my code on an example code that prints `argc` and `argv` values when called from the command line.

I'm running Debian 8 64-bit

Comment: You are breaking values in callee-save registers `%edi` and `%ebx`, so I guess it may cause some troubles.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to have more information about this segfault ?

Comment: No i didn't. Honestly I don't know how to do it. Professor used lldb one time during class, my knowledge stops there for now..

Comment: And here I go again: the FIRST thing you need to learn when programming C/C++ is how to use the debugger. The second in this case is: Write your assembler function in C first, then produce disassembly to see how the ABI is done. Then write your own while being a bit less in the dark.

Comment: @BitTickler : I generally think knowing/having the ABI is important before you try to figure out the calling convention. It may not be immediately obvious what is going on by looking at the disassembly. I am all for a debugger, but I find actually knowing the ABI is better than trying to guess from the disassembly. As it stands, on top of the registers being clobbered GCC is compiling 64-bit on Debian 64-bit (it lacks -m32). So the OP will either have to rewrite the assembler function as 64-bit, or compile the _C_ code as 32-bit with `-m32` option.

Comment: The 64-bit Linux ABI (and calling convention) can be found in this [document](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) . The 32-bit Linux ABI can be found in this [document](https://01.org/sites/default/files/file_attach/intel386-psabi-1.0.pdf)

Comment: I compiled with `-m32` and the error was gone! Meanwhile I learned a little about disassembly and using gdb and you're right, I should learn better that. Well my code still gives uncorrect value, but i'll have to figure it out. The segmentation fault was given by a 64-bit compilation (default for gcc I assume). Thanks all for forcing me into gdb!

Comment: Have you considered looking up the manual for the debugger, `lldb`, that your professor demonstrated??

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes - he needs to decide if he wants to write 64 or 32 bit assembler code (different ABI). The ABI specification for linux type of systems can be easily googled (differs from Win64 ABI, btw.). There is no need for figuring out if you can simply look it up.

Comment: @BitTickler : That is what I said, and I did post both the links for the 64-bit and 32-bit Linux ABIs. I posted the Linux ones because he did say this was Debian 64-bit. If it was a Windows question I would have directed them to the MSDN pages that describe the Windows calling conventions for 32 and 64-bit.

Comment: One way to eliminate the need for _EDI_ is to loop through the array from end to beginning. You could use  _ECX_ as a countdown loop counter. But if you don't do that then you'll need to push the contents of %edi (since it needs to be preserved in a function) and pop it at the end. The reason your result is wrong is because I think you have the comparison `cmpl %ebx,%eax` reversed. You may have meant `cmpl %eax,%ebx` . Your comparison and branch finds the minimum value.     both these lines can be eliminated `jmp end_function` `end_function:` . Jumping to next instruction not very useful.

Comment: Since your function has no local variables you can also get rid of the stack frame prologue and epilogue and reference the parameters just as easily relative to _ESP_ rather than _EBP_. (Of course the offset of each parameter is 4 less in that scenario).

Comment: Yeah that was  inverted.  Thanks for the tip for both `cmpl` and `jmp`. It's kinda the first time I write an assembly function, I'm still learning my way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems were:

- not preserving `%ebx` and `%edi`
- not compiling for 32 bit (had to use `-m32` flag for gcc)
- `cmpl` operands were inverted

Thanks everybody, problem is solved.
I'll  focus more on debugging tools to (disassembling and running step by step was very useful)!

Comment: You might want to remove the `.code32` directive from your assembly file. Without it you'd probably have gotten an assembler error because you didn't use `-m32`.